# Cannot read 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to figure out why this code doesn't bind to the class. In all cases of `state` properties not being defined that I have read, it was due to a lack of the following line:

```
this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
```

---

But my code includes that line for my functions. I am, however, making an HTTP request with promises that I suspect are throwing off the compiler, despite the code being identical to the Axios [example](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Jumbotron } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Parallax, Background } from 'react-parallax';
import Fox from './fox.jpg';
var BASE_URL =  "http://127.0.0.1:8080/";
var BIN_API = BASE_URL + "binter-info";

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tradingFrom: '...',
      tradingTo: '...',
      result: '...'
    };
    this.retrieveValue = this.retrieveValue.bind(this);
    this.updateResult = this.updateResult.bind(this);
  }

  updateResult(str) {
    var self = this;
    if (str != null) {
      self.setState({
        result: str,
      });
    }
  }

  retrieveValue() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('App: retrieveValue executed...');
    let symbol = this.state.tradingTo + this.state.tradingFrom;
  //  Make Server Request
    axios.get(BIN_API, {
          params: {
              symbol: symbol,
          }
      }).then(function (response) {
    console.log("Good");
    //console.log(response);
    self.updateResult(response.data);
    console.log('this.state.result is now ' + this.state.result); // LINE 49
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);         // LINE 51
    self.updateResult("ERROR");
    });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Parallax className='par'
      blur={6}
     bgImage={Fox}
      bgImageAlt="Fox"
      strength={200}
    >
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <div style={{ height: '200px' }} />
    </Parallax>
        <Jumbotron>
        <h2 className="App-Text">The following is a <strong>BETA_VERSION </strong>website.</h2>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Button className="App-Button" onClick={this.retrieveValue}> Retrieve Value </Button>
        <div className="TXTAREA">
          <p className="TA-p">{this.state.result}</p>
        </div>
        <Jumbotron>
        <h1 className="App-Text">but wait..</h1>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Jumbotron>
        <h1 className="App-Text">theres more!</h1>
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

My error is this:

```
App.js:51 TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at App.js:49
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? `App.js:51` points to a closing `</p`> in your code sample. Have you omitted some import statements? What is actually line `49` and `51` of your code?

Comment: @DanPantry It is all there now, I omitted the imports and the `render` function earlier because I didn't think those were important but now the lines should match up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is occuring because you are calling `this.state` inside a Promise callback from Axios. `this` will be `undefined`.

```
console.log('this.state.result is now ' + this.state.result);
```

Note that you can avoid this by using arrow functions rather than the function expression syntax you are using. This will bind `this` in the lexical context (lexical context meaning 'where the arrow function is defined' rather than 'where the function is called')

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      tradingFrom: "...",
      tradingTo: "...",
      result: "..."
    };
    this.retrieveValue = this.retrieveValue.bind(this);
  }

  updateResult(str) {
    var self = this;
    if (str != null) {
      self.setState({
        result: str
      });
    }
  }

  retrieveValue() {
    console.log("App: retrieveValue executed...");
    let symbol = this.state.tradingTo + this.state.tradingFrom;
    //  Make Server Request
    axios
      .get(BIN_API, {
        params: {
          symbol: symbol
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.updateResult(response.data);
        console.log("this.state.result is now " + this.state.result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.updateResult("ERROR");
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button className="App-Button" onClick={this.retrieveValue}>
          {" "}Retrieve Value{" "}
        </Button>
        <div className="TXTAREA">
          <p className="TA-p">
            {this.state.result}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the pattern to `bind` functions in the constructor of a React component is only used because when you pass in a function like you do in the `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={this.retrieveValue}
```

You lose the `this` context when it is called. The ways to solve this are to use `bind` or arrow functions; the reason bind is used is because it avoids creating a new function object on each `render` call. So, with that said, you do *not* need to `bind` `updateResult`.

EDIT: Note that this code concerns a previous revision of the OPs code, but the issue is the same.